# Site Search for 200k Page Site

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

Looking to get a site search functionality implemented on my site. I have roughly 200,000 pages (it's a collectors database type site).

I normally use Google CSE, but since it runs off of the regular index, I'm worried that Google may not include all of the pages since they may consider them duplicate entries of other existing websites.

I've looked at SOLR and Sphinx and both look too complex for me to set up. I was considering using Sphider which I have used before, but I'm not sure if that's a good, secure solution or not.

Does anyone have any feedback? For the record, I am using innodb and fulltext searches are not supported. I would like to have search suggestion functionality implemented at some point (autosuggest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the record, I am using innodb and fulltext searches are not supported.

A "simple" solution to your problem would be to upgrade to [MySQL 5.6.4+](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html) which does have fulltext indexes for innodb.  From their website:

> Full-text searches are supported for InnoDB and MyISAM tables only. FULLTEXT index support for InnoDB tables requires MySQL 5.6.4 or higher.

The big focus of 5.6 was to improve read performance, which sounds like would benefit you greatly having 200k pages.

Comment: Ok, but would the fulltext search functionality be as good as something like sphinx?

Comment: Sphinx will likely perform better: at least according to the googling I've been doing!  However, if you don't want the hassle of third party libraries, you can always implement InnoDB FTS.  If your primary concern is speed, definitely take the time to setup Sphinx or any of the other options out there.